# Ender 3 Pro build not getting power after initial setup

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply

I have an Ender 3 Pro that has yet to be used, since after initial out of the box assembly it doesn't seem to get power. I plug it in, flip the switch, and nothing. No fan in the PSU, no screen flicker, no sign of life in any way.

Double checked all the power cables going from PSU to motor, screen, extruder, etc. and they are all secured. The XT60 cable is firmly connected.

I checked the outlet, but it powers my desktop PSU fine. I checked the cord, but it works for other PSUs. I assumed it was the power supply, but replacing it with a new one gives me the same issue.

What other steps can I take to diagnose/fix this issue??

Comment: Have you checked the 110/220 V switch?

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! So, you checked and replaced the PSU and still no power to the controller board. You must have a broken controller board then, or some cables? This sounds like a DOA, you should have contacted the seller immediately before tinkering.

Comment: @agarza No I haven't, what should I do with that? I'm assuming you mean the voltage switch on the PSU to select input voltage?

Comment: @0scar Yeah I probably should've, but I assembled this a while ago and then got super busy with school and work and forgot about it. Controller board sounds like a likely culprit, as the wires all look in fairly good shape and the connections are decent as far as I can see. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can check whether a power supply is woking by looking at an LED near the output cables. Most power supplies have a(n) (green) LED connected to the output that lights up when the PSU is (mostly) working. If you want a more precise check, you can use a voltmeter to check the output voltage, it should be either 12 V or 24 V depending on the power supply (I think Ender 3 V2 uses 24 volt, but I am not sure). You say you have the same result with two different PSUs, which means you should look elsewhere as others suggested. Some mainboards use fuses, some do not, check whether those fine.